# List files and sort them manually Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I saw similar questions, but not one that resolves my need. I´m using Notepad++. I´m working with more than 50 files taking advantage (for navigation, aka, go to one file to other) of the “Document Panel” (left column with all my files). But, since I´m adding files, and I need to ORDER (sort) manually some of  these files… I´m stuck! Anyone knows a good plugin for that or how to resolve it? I need to have an easy list with all my files and can sort them (change position) as I need. For example, move x file close to y file to not stay “jumping” from one part of the panel list to other. 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just use the tab bar (along the top). You can drag and drop the tabs to rearrange them ...

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I am doing that! But when you are working with several files and changing the "position", it turns you crazy hahaha!

Answer (score 7):

> **List files and sort them manually Notepad++**
>
> I need to ORDER (sort) manually some of these files… I´m stuck! Anyone
>   knows a good plugin for that or how to resolve it? I need to have an
>   easy list with all my files and can sort them (change position) as I
>   need. For example, move x file close to y file to not stay “jumping”
>   from one part of the panel list to other.

I've included a couple different methods to help you potentially:

1. Easily sort all opened tabs in **Notepad++** by either `Name`, `Path`, or
   `Type`.

   - Depending on your need, sorting by one of these fields may help you be able to more quickly sort or move them around with the moving of the tabs.
2. Easily get a full list of all tabs in **Notepad++** without needing to scroll through those with the actual tabs in the tab bar or the arrows next to the tab bar.

   - Depending on your need, getting to the needed tab more quickly this way may help you be able to more quickly sort or move itaround with the moving of its tab.

---

### METHOD 1

It appears that **Notepad++** has a built-in order tabs by file name in ascending or descending order.

Below are some screen shots with examples but here are the navigation steps:

Up top select **`Window`** | **`Windows`**, and then in the **Windows** window options, click on the **`Name column`** to sort in either ascending or descending order, and then click the <kbd>**Sort tabs**</kbd> option and <kbd>**OK**</kbd> when complete.

### Using <kbd>**Sort Tabs**</kbd> Option

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Anitmated Gif (click to enlarge)**

[image]

---

### METHOD 2

When in **Notepad++** and you click on an active sheet, press and hold down on <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> and then press <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> to bring up the tabs list. At this point keep <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> held down and press <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> however many times to toggle to the next tab in the list. You can also use the down arrow rather than <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> after you press <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> once and then use the down arrow rather than <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> to toggle through the tabs list (see below for a visual).

### Using <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd> + <kbd>**Tab**</kbd> Option

**Anitmated Gif (click to enlarge)**

[image]

-

Comment: @Tom did this work for you by chance? If so, please see [**Accepting An Answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you get a chance to ensure you understand how that works with this site.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.  OP wants to **manually arrange the order**.

Comment: @DavidPostill I just added further detail clarifying the options and how these may be helpful methods with the built-in Notepad++ functionality to assist the OP with resolving the need for the manual sort order that'll need to be done aftewards. Usually when you sort the order of something you have to sort by some common value or attribute so perhaps using either of these methods will help him more easily reach the ultimate goal if he indeed has a sort order that's just random depending on what's opened and what he may be working, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are not overlooking anything,

#### This feature is not implemented yet.

There is [feature request #946](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/946) registered for this issue. Keep an eye on it to see when it gets implemented.

While it is missing, you can use several workarounds, but there is no direct way of reordering files in the list ("Doc Switcher") you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

To display Document Switcher, go to Settings > Preferences, then in General settings, in the Document List Panel, check-in "Show". It will display the list of open files in a panel on the left. In this panel, you can click on "Name" column, and it will sort files by alphabetical order only in Document Switcher.

In addition to that, you can sort tabs by name using Window > Windows... "Sort tabs" button.

It seems those "features" are independent.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see `Document List Panel` nor `"Name" column` in the `Settings > Preferences`. It will be usefull if you post a screen shot.

Comment: I just updated, is it more explicit?